# Deleting DOM elements with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am currently having trouble figuring out exactly how to delete DOM elements.

I know that you can find the element you want by id and then delete it, the thing is in my case that i create the elements with a function each time the 'create' key is pressed. I also add a close button to each element to be able to delete it.

I know that you probably can find this online but i don't even know what to search for.

I want to add a click event to each button to be able to detect which one was pressed and then delete the corresponding element.

This is what I use to create the elements each time the button is pressed.

(I use the RE:DOM library to add the elements)

```
var count_id = 0;
function addChart(){
    const test = el('.row',
                el('.col',
                el('.card mb-3',[
                    el('.card-header',[
                        el('i', {class: 'fa fa-area-chart'}),
                        el('a', {class: 'btn float-right', id: 'close-chart-'+count_id.toString()},
                            el('i', {class: 'fa fa-times'}))]),
                    el('.card-body',
                        el('#areaTest', {style:'width : 100%;'},
                        el('.loader'))),
                    el('.card-footer',
                    el('.row',
                    el('.col-lg-2',[
                        el('h6','Select a date'),
                        el('div', {class:'input-group date','data-provide':'datapicker'},[
                        el('.form-control', {type:'text'}),
                        el('.input-group-addon')])])
                    ))])
                ));

    test.id = count_id.toString();
    mount(document.getElementById('charts-container'),test);
    count_id++;
    console.log(count_id);
}
```

Relevant HTML section. I am adding everything in this container.

```
<div class="row">
    <div id="charts-container" class="container">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please post your html and css also so we can test the javascript function functionalities?

Comment: I am using bootstrap so i don't have any css of my own for this. I'll post the relevant html section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create function delete and pass it id of element which is dynamicly assigned, you can see one example below, element has unique id "el-" and id assigned, that id is passed to function by button click and rest is done by **remove()** function

```
    <button onclick="delete(123)"> DELETE </button>
    <p id="el-123"> i will be deleted </p>


    <script>
    function delete(id){
      document.getElementById("el-" + id).remove();
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add click event on the element and pass its reference. And then you can call this function on its click event.

```
<div #divRef onclick="deleteElement(divRef)">I'm a div</div>
```

In script:

```
function deleteElement(element) {
    element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
}
```

Comment: I am guessing by element you mean all of it not just the button. If so where do i pass it's reference to after i create the element in the function? Sorry for the stupid question...

Answer (score 0):

For your button to be clicked to delete the referred element(with parent i am assuming as corresponding complete row should be deleted), taking the structure as:

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <span>ele to be deleted</span>
    <input class="delBtn" type ="button">Delete</input>
</div>

 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
           $(".delBtn").click(function(event){
              $(event.target).closest(".parentDiv").remove();
          });
      }); 
 </script>
```